# very old SQL file

Tags: windows, legacy

I have a customer that has software written in 1992.  They run a VM to run windows in 16bit mode to allow the software to still run.  But they are now wanting to convert the program and data.  The data is all in one file.  It has the extension of `.000` so no help there.

I did a lot of googling, but really don't have a good plan on how to export this out to anything.  Basically I could use some ideas on how to get this file exported into tables.  Or even csv files, whatever!  My guess is I need to VM up something like windows 95 and then load up ????? to allow it to browse the data or at least call something to allow me to export a file...

I have tried SQL recovery programs that go back to version 7, but none recognize this.  If anyone knows one that would go back to the real old stuff?  Also the first two chars of the file are: "¥Z"  My guess is its SQL server 1 or 1.1,

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: I don't think SQL ever worked on a 16bit Windows. And it sure didn't use a single file with the extensions `.000`. Are you **sure** application is using SQL Server

Comment: I would love to be sure!  I am pretty sure its SQL like, and from that time period - early 1990s.  The extension I think is just whatever the programmer guy decided to call it.  It could have been .dat or anything.  Another tidbit is that fields seem to be separated with \0, so you get \0Fred\0314\0Tom\0555

Comment: Does this help: https://serverfault.com/questions/466222/migrate-old-ms-sql-4-2-circa-1992-db-dump-to-ms-sql-2005/466345

Comment: As the application is still running you can surely see the processes running and if any external service is being called? There doesn't seem any evidence that this has anything to do with SQL Server so I've removed that tag.

Comment: If it really is that old it would have been running OS/2. But I have never heard of the .000 file extension.

Comment: the .000 extension is pretty much I am convinced unrelated to the file, there are also files ( not used in a decade ) that have extension .001 and .dat  and .sav and .old and .tst  which all have the same general format as the main data file .001

I am pretty certain that its SQL like - good tip Martin on the processes running, sadly the guy renamed whatever is the process to his name.  LOL, I will probably dig into the file that is running, maybe some answer there...

Comment: Johnny Fitz - "In short, this is a tedious and time consuming project." LOL, yep I am thinking so too, but that looks like the best option for me right now...  I will work on that a day or so.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should try to open the file on Hexadecimal Editor and read his header.

Sometimes you can discover how was the database analyzing it.

If the file is not so bigger, you can try it using the notepad.

Don't forget to try it on a copy of original file.

Comment: "¥Z\u0006\0\u0010 °\a\u0010 °\a\0€+*og,\r\u0010\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0€\0\0\a\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\u0001Œ\u001c\0\0\u001a\n\u0001\0\0\0\u0010€\0\0\u0002\0\u001e\0\u0010°\0\0\u0003\0M\0\u0010à\0\0\u0004\0n\0\u0010\u0010\u0001\0\u0005\0—\0\u0010@\u0001\0\u0006\0µ\0\u0010p\u0001\0\a\0¿\0\u0010 \u0001\0\b\0ç\0\u0010Ð\u0001\0\t\0\n\u0001\u0010\0\u0002\0\n\0\u0015\u0001\u00100\u0002\0\v\0c\u0001\u0010`\u0002\0\f\0™\u0002\u0010\u0090\u0002\0\r\0¿\u0002\u0010À\u0002\0\u000e\0Ñ\u0002\u0010ð\u0002\0\u000f\0\a\u0003\u0010 \u0003\0\u0010\0(\u0003\u0010P\u0003\0\u0011\0

Comment: This fragment is small to conclude something.

I was thinking, that maybe the database is a Clipper file or a simple DAT file. 

You need to scroll the file to try to find some fragment can help you.

Comment: did some more digging and found this little bit of code:

:SrcDir=%PackageHome;
:DstDir=%PackageHome;
#drop table DOC_GROUPS;
#drop table DOC_LIST;

:ListingsReports=select 1 from DOC_GROUPS where GROUP_NAME=~Listings Reports~;
?ListingsReports=insert into DOC_GROUPS(GROUP_NAME) VALUES(~Listings Reports~);
:File=select 1 from DOC_LIST where DOC_GROUPS_1=&ListingsReports and DOC_NAME=~Auto Invoice List~;
?File=insert into DOC_LIST(DOC_GROUPS_1, DOC_NAME,DOC_SYS,DOC_DED) VALUES(&ListingsReports,~Auto Invoice List~,~z--ARROW~,~autoinvl~);
copy &SrcDir\autoinvl.ded &DstDir\&File;